# Is there a way to make a U-bend using a Hossfeld type bender?

Tags: metalworking

I want to make the following bend in 3/16" or 1/4" x 1.5" steel flat stock:

[image]

The problem is that on most bench type benders, I don't think you can do two opposing bends like this. I know I can do it on a hydraulic press with a 1.5" block die, but I don't have that equipment. Is there a way to do this on an ordinary bender either of the Hossfeld type or an auto-body type bracket bender?

Comment: This question has languished for awhile.  Has it been overtaken by events or are you still looking for an answer?  When you first posted it, I wasn't sure what the issue was.  I've made bends in this shape.  The limitation is the dimensions of the tooling.  If you're still looking for an answer, can you clarify the nature of the problem?